# Exception with a simple binary code converter (2)

Tags: java, arrays, exception, binary, decimal

I've got a problem with my simple binary code converter in Java (applet):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class dual_convert extends Applet implements ActionListener{
  TextField dual;
  TextField decimal;
  Button dual_b;
  Button decimal_b;
  Label dual_l;
  Label decimal_l;
  int decimal_i;
  String dual_s [];
  int dual_i;
  int decimal_e;

  public void init() {
    setLayout(null);

    dual = new TextField();
    dual.setBounds(90,10,100,25);
    add(dual);

    decimal = new TextField();
    decimal.setBounds(90,40,100,25);
    add(decimal);

    decimal_l = new Label("Decimal:");
    decimal_l.setBounds(10,40,80,25);
    add(decimal_l);

    dual_l = new Label("Binary:");
    dual_l.setBounds(10,10,80,25);
    add(dual_l);

    dual_b = new Button ("Convert");
    dual_b.setBounds(200,10,80,25);
    add(dual_b);
    dual_b.addActionListener(this);

    decimal_b = new Button ("Convert");
    decimal_b.setBounds(200,40,80,25);
    add(decimal_b);
    decimal_b.addActionListener(this);

  }

  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==decimal_b) {
      decimal_i = Integer.parseInt(decimal.getText());  
      int ih = 0;
      dual.setText("");
      while (decimal_i>0) {
        dual.setText((decimal_i % 2)+dual.getText());
        decimal_i = decimal_i / 2; 
        ih++;
      }    
    }

    if (e.getSource()==dual_b) {
      dual_s = dual.getText().split("");
      dual_i = dual_s.length;
      decimal.setText("");
      for (int i=0;dual_i>0;dual_i--) {
        decimal_e = decimal_e + (Integer.parseInt(dual_s[dual_i-1]) * 2^i); 
        i++;
      } 
      decimal.setText(decimal_e+"");       
    } 
  }
}
```

It throws this exception by pressing Convert Binary to Decimal:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""     at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)  at
>   dual_convert.actionPerformed(dual_convert.java:65)    at
>   java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:409)   at
>   java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:377)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

For the binary-->decimal conversion I use this system (Is there even an other?):

100101 = [ ( 1 ) × 25 ] + [ ( 0 ) × 24 ] + [ ( 0 ) × 23 ] + [ ( 1 ) × 22 ] + [ ( 0 ) × 21 ] + [ ( 1 ) × 20 ]

100101 = [ 1 × 32 ] + [ 0 × 16 ] + [ 0 × 8 ] + [ 1 × 4 ] + [ 0 × 2 ] + [ 1 × 1 ]

100101 = 3710

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number

Comment: I'll give you a hint and let you do the debugging. The error message `NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` means you are trying to convert an empty string to a number. That doesn't work.

Comment: That's clear, but it even appears if I write something in the dual TextField, it shouldn't be emtpy.

Comment: Alright, I've found the issue: split("") doesn't create an zero, so when the for loop reaches dual_i=0 it throws the exception. I had to change the condition to dual_i>1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
dual_s = dual.getText().split("");
```

returns a `String[]` with a leading empty string. Instead of doing it the way you are doing it right now, I advise you to use a `char[]` to store each character of the input string. You can get it with

```
dual.getText().toCharArray();
```

and traverse it using [`Character.digit(char ch, int radix);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29) instead of `Integer.parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that this line:

```
decimal_i = Integer.parseInt(decimal.getText());
```

has a problem, namely, that you're trying to convert a blank String into an Integer. You must guard against this.

Comment: Line 65 is 'decimal_e = decimal_e + (Integer.parseInt(dual_s[dual_i-1]) * 2^i);' not the line you posted.

Comment: @user2651027: then (obviously) `dual_s[dual_i - 1]` is an empty string.

Comment: The idea is that your calling, `Integer.parseInt(someText)` where someText is blank.

Answer (score -1):

As with Splungebob's answer, you need to guard against that condition, but the conversion can be done with the API. See the [Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method.

Comment: No, how can this method help when when `s` is an empty string?

Comment: @jlordo perhaps my wording was ambiguous, I've edited it now. I meant that the input validation was still required, but the actual conversion from base 2 to base 10 is supported by parseInt.